# List Compression prints [none, none, none]

Tags: python

I have a question about list compressions within Python.
I am learning through Udacity and uploading my answers/code to an IDE (I could be wrong about it being an IDE) they have through my browser.
Before uploading I like to test my code to see if it actually works...as of now I am using Windows Powershell. So the code below is run on Powershell. But my question is...why when I run my code does it print [None, None, None, None] but when I print(new_list) I get ['a','b','c','d']

```
letters = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
[new_list.append(letter.lower()) for letter in letters]
print(new_list)
```

When I upload the code to the browser I get a 'Nonetype' object is not an iterable. Makes sense... considering Powershell tells me it is initially viewed as a Nonetype. But, why?

Comment: Where is new_list defined?

Comment: `append` modifies the list in-place and returns `None`.

Comment: btw it's a comprehension, not a compression.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. It should be:

```py
letters = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
new_list = [letter.lower() for letter in letters]
print(new_list)
```

E.g. have a [look here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp) for comparison of list comprehension vs for loop.

The above code snippet with a list comprehension equals to:

```py
letters = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
new_list = list()
for letter in letters:
    new_list.append(letter.lower())
print(new_list)
```

Comment: Oh interesting... I thought you could assign everything to new_list within the list compression. Thank you!

Comment: I mean, of course that is possible, but the point with a list comprehension is to create a new list with a desired content. As myrmica explained in a comment, the append() method doesn't return anythin, hence the list comprehension in your question would result in a list containing only `None` values

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing something like this:

```py
letters = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
new_list = [letter.lower() for letter in letters]
print(new_list)
```

The error comes from this line:

```
[new_list.append(letter.lower()) for letter in letters]
```

On `new_list.append(...)` you have not declared the new_list array variable (it doesn't exist), and you're telling it to append something to it.

List comprehensions are a replacement for creating a new list and then appending to it. You create it and populate it in one go